# How can I downgrade from keynote 10.1 to 10.0?

Tags: keynote, iwork, downgrade, productivity, slideshow

Well, I updated to Keynote 10.1 and it hangs when starting the slideshow of the presentation. All of them went well on v10.0, but they don´t in v10.1.

Any advice or suggestion. (Running in macOS 10.15.6)

Comment: Sadly you cannot downgrade.  Did you try saving the Keynote presentation to a new file?  Or recreating the presentation and copy pasting the slides/data?

Comment: While I have not tried this myself I have heard that restoring from a TimeMachine backup (assuming you have one) *might* do the trick.

Comment: @SteveChambers I did it in my iMac, and it works. However, I cannot do it in my Macbook :(

Comment: @JamesBrickley your suggestion does not work. I have noticed that even changing, for instance, the transition for one slide, and trying to see a preview in the editor, Keynote hangs.